# SwiftUI-Updating text and slider in a subview while sending back binded value to main view

Tags: ios, swiftui

On a page I need 15 of the same view which contains sliders that alter the value, text that also needs to update, and dividers, so i decided to try reusing views instead of having 15 of them and so I created "SliderDividerSubview":

```
SliderDividerSubView(numberValue: $formOneResult.s31a, name: "I felt that I belonged at my school")
HStack{
    Text("I felt that I belonged at my school")
        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
        .padding(.leading)
    VStack{
        Slider(value: $formOneResult.s31a, in: 1...5, step: 1){
            Text("Do you agree with this statement?") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }minimumValueLabel:{
            Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }maximumValueLabel:{
            Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }
        Text(GetFeelingText(formOneResult.s31a))
            .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 12))
    }
}
Divider()
HStack{
    Text("I felt respected at school.")
        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
        .padding(.leading)
    VStack{
        Slider(value: $formOneResult.s31a, in: 1...5, step: 1){
            Text("Do you agree with this statement?") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }minimumValueLabel:{
            Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }maximumValueLabel:{
            Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
        }
        Text(GetFeelingText(formOneResult.s31a))
            .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 12))
    }
}
Divider()
...
```

HOWEVER, even though the code builds fine, and it stores the value in that s31a object correctly, it doesnt correctly update the text which I am using "wrappedValue" for as you can see in the code.

Here's the reusable subview i created, any idea what i should look into?

```
struct SliderDividerSubView: View {
    @State var numberValue : Binding<Float>
    @State var name : String

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(name)
                    .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                    .padding(.leading)
                VStack{
                    Slider(value: numberValue, in: 1...5, step: 1){
                        Text("Do you agree with this statement?") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }minimumValueLabel:{
                        Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }maximumValueLabel:{
                        Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }
                    Text(GetFeelingText(numberValue.wrappedValue))
                        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 12))
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
    
    func GetFeelingText(_ score: Float) -> String {
        switch (score){
        case 1.0:
            return "Strongly Disagree"
        case 2.0:
            return "Disagree"
        case 3.0:
            return "Neither Agree not Disagree"
        case 4.0:
            return "Agree"
        case 5.0:
            return "Strongly Agree"
        default:
            return "Neither Agree not Disagree"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the video attached, the first item is using the reusable view which is why it is misbehaving, I need the Text to also update like the others:

[image: Video of problem described]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using `@Binding var numberValue: Float` and
`Slider(value: $numberValue, in: 1...5, step: 1)` as shown in this example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numberValue: [Float] = Array(repeating: 3.0, count: 15)
    
    var body: some View {
        // only for testing
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<15, id: \.self) { index in
                SliderDividerSubView(numberValue: $numberValue[index], name: "belong to school \(index)") 
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SliderDividerSubView: View {
    @Binding var numberValue: Float // <-- here
    @State var name : String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(name)
                    .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                    .padding(.leading)
                VStack{
                    Slider(value: $numberValue, in: 1...5, step: 1){ // <-- here
                        Text("Do you agree with this statement?") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }minimumValueLabel:{
                        Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }maximumValueLabel:{
                        Text(" ") //Is never visible, but is needed
                    }
                    Text(GetFeelingText(numberValue))  // <-- here
                        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 12))
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
    
    func GetFeelingText(_ score: Float) -> String {
        switch (score){
        case 1.0:
            return "Strongly Disagree"
        case 2.0:
            return "Disagree"
        case 3.0:
            return "Neither Agree not Disagree"
        case 4.0:
            return "Agree"
        case 5.0:
            return "Strongly Agree"
        default:
            return "Neither Agree not Disagree"
        }
    }
}
```